# Batch file to run a java app. How to port it in Mac?

Tags: java, macos, batch-file

I have a tiny batch file to kick off my java app:

its code is something as simple as

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

(in reality it's slightly more complicated as we set a few properties)

A friend of mine has a mac. He has java installed on his mac.
But how do we run this batch from mac ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following code into a file and run `chmod +x <filename>` to make it executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited. Thanks Nicola.

Answer (score 1):

If the Java app. is a desktop app. with a GUI, a good way to launch it is using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS provides the ability to set properties in the JNLP launch file.

JWS works on all desktop JREs.  E.G. it will work on Windows, Mac. and *nix.